# Can not import modules from gi.repository

Tags: python, ubuntu, import, gtk, gobject

I can not import modules from gi.repository.
Specifically not Gtk and GObject.

I experienced this error both on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and after reinstall
also on Linux Mint 17.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
```

Results in the 'unresolved reference' warning for the respective
modules. Interestingly enough my Gtk GUI can be compiled and works
perfectly fine. Yet, GObject is entirely out of function.

I tried to work around with altering import statements such as:

```
from gi.repository.Gtk import*
```

Even hard coding the import path via:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi')
```

*None of these approaches have solved this frustrating error so far.*

I have not found any concluding help or basic info on this issue,
neither anywhere on the web nor in Linux forums or here on stackoverflow.
I am not sure whether this problem lies on the Python or the Linux side of things.

**Can anybody suggest how to solve this issue?**
What additional information do I need to provide eventually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If on a Debian-based system such as Ubuntu, you probably need to install the `gir1.2-gtk-3.0` package and other similarly named packages for other libraries. I don't know what the name of the package would be on Mint, but it's probably something similar.

Comment: Thanks. The package gir1.2-gtk-3.0 was already installed. The failure persists despite of it.

Comment: For me upgrading `gir1.2-gtk-3.0` helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On Wheezy (Debian 7.8) installing `python3-gi` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this issue with some old github python examples and it helped for me to add lines:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
```

reference:
https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html